# How to send User to User request with the Facebook SDK 3.1 for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to invite a user's facebook friend to participate with the user within an iOS app. It is my understanding that I want to use a User to User Request and *not* an App Request.

I am unsure of how to accomplish this though.

According to the [Send Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/) page, there should be a "Facebook" class which has a "dialog" method.  This does not appear to exist within the Facebook SDK 3.1 for iOS though.

How then do I send a User to User Request with the Facebook SDK 3.1 for iOS?

Thanks

Comment: Are there any users left on iOS 3.1? It's really time to upgrade your target... http://tewha.net/2012/06/dont-write-new-apps-that-target-ios-4/

Comment: sorry, not the iOS 3.1 SDK, the "Facebook SDK 3.1 for iOS"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a detailed guide about how to do this on the [Facebook Developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/) site.

Don't forget to follow this rule that is mentionned in the guide but can be easy to miss (emphasis mine):

> import the `Facebook.h` header file and **replace** the Facebook framework `<FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>` import declaration

In other words, if you want to avoid having lots of *duplicate symbol* errors from the compiler, make sure you are **replacing** the `FacebookSDK.h` import by `Facebook.h` instead of importing both.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution is to reference the Facebook deprecated headers

~Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/A/DeprecatedHeaders

Then using an FBDialog:

```
[self.facebook dialog:@"apprequests"
           andParams:params
         andDelegate:self];
```